# Syllogisms in LateX, syllogism package alignment issues?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-styles

Does anyone have a solution to author line by line syllogisms in LateX?  Preferably with comments to the side?

I tried the [Syllogism Package](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/syllogism/syllogism.pdf), however alignment under the premises if off.  Specifically the horizontal line before the conclusion is shifted right and there is abnormal spacing between premises and conclusion horizontal line.  This only appears when I use shorter text "A is B" etc for the propositions.

[image: syllogism package alignment issue]

Code that produces:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{syllogism}
\begin{document}

\syllog{Every man except Socrates is musician} %
{Socrates is a man} %
{Socrates is not a musician},

\syllog{A is B} %
{B is C} %
{A is C},

\syllog[(S1)]{A is B} %
{B is C} %
{A is C},

\end{document}
```

At the moment, I'm using the bussproofs package, however it lacks support for each premise on its own line.  All the premises end up on a single line as shown below.  I would like the behavior of the syllogism package, however with the alignment problem fixed.

[image]

```
\usepackage{bussproofs}

\begin{prooftree}
    \AxiomC{MaN}
    \AxiomC{MoX}
    \BinaryInfC{NoX}
\end{prooftree}

\begin{prooftree}
    \AxiomC{M belongs to all N}
    \AxiomC{No M belongs to some X}
    \BinaryInfC{No N belongs to some X}
\end{prooftree}
```

Any guidance appreciated.  Also, any tags suggestions that would better cover this also appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please provide a small example document with the `syllogism` package that shows the wrong alignment, and a description or mock-up screenshot of how you want the alignment to be? That makes it easier to understand the issue, reproduce it, and possibly suggest improvements.

Comment: What do you mean by “alignment was off”?

Comment: It would be much more useful if you show how you'd like to present the syllogisms, not how you *don't* like.

Comment: I updated per comments.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite hard to understand the way how `syllogism` sets the various dimensions, which has very weird consequences, as you discovered.

Here's a thorough reimplementation of the `\syllog` macro. The syllogism will never exceed the current column width minus twice the “prespace”. No line break is allowed before the final “therefore” symbol.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfp}
\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage{syllogism}

\makeatletter
\def\@syllog[#1]#2#3#4{%
  % Define the propositions -----------------------------------------------
  \def\@SYLpropA{\ignorespaces#2\unskip}%
  \def\@SYLpropB{\ignorespaces#3\SY@PuncPB\unskip}%
  \def\@SYLpropC{\ignorespaces#4\unskip\nolinebreak\hspace{\SY@SpConEG}\SY@ErgoSign}%
  %
  \settowidth{\SY@LenPA}{\@SYLpropA}
  \settowidth{\SY@LenPB}{\@SYLpropB}
  \settowidth{\SY@LenC}{\@SYLpropC}
  %
  \setlength{\SY@LenLab}{\widthof{#1}}%
  \ifdim\SY@LenLab>\z@
    \addtolength{\SY@LenLab}{\SY@SpLabel}
  \fi
  %
  % Set the rule's length ----------------------------------------------
  \setlength{\SY@LenRule}{%
    \fpeval{max(\SY@LenPA,\SY@LenPB,\SY@LenC)}pt}%
  \ifdim\dimexpr\SY@LenRule+\SY@Pre+\SY@LenLab\relax>\dimexpr\columnwidth-\SY@Pre\relax
    \setlength{\SY@LenRule}{\columnwidth-2\SY@Pre-\SY@LenLab}%
  \fi
  % Construction of the Syllogism ----------------------------------------
  \par\vspace{\SY@LenSepA}\noindent % V-space before the syllogism
  \if@SYParam                       % Conditional H-space before syllogism
      \hspace{\SY@Pre}#1\hspace{\SY@SpLabel}%
   \else
      \hspace{\SY@Pre}%
  \fi
  %
  \begin{minipage}{\SY@LenRule}
    \raggedright
    \begin{list}{}
      {%
        \setlength{\parsep}{\z@}%
        \setlength{\itemsep}{\z@}%
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{1em}%
        \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
        \setlength{\labelwidth}{0pt}%
        \setlength{\labelsep}{0pt}%
      }
      \item \@SYLpropA
      \item \@SYLpropB\vspace{\dimexpr-\ht\strutbox+\dp\strutbox}
      \item \rule{\SY@LenRule}{\SY@HiRule}
      \item \@SYLpropC
    \end{list}
  \end{minipage}
  \par\vspace{\SY@LenSepB}%                 V-space after the syllogism
  %
  \@SYRestoreBooleans% Restore booleans
}
\makeatletter



\begin{document}

\syllog{Every man except Socrates is musician}
  {Socrates is a man}
  {Socrates is not a musician}

\syllog{Every man except Socrates is musician Every man except Socrates is musician}
  {Socrates is a man}
  {Socrates is not a musician}

\syllog{A is B}
  {B is C}
  {A is C}

\syllog[(S1)]{A is B}
  {B is C}
  {A is C}

\end{document}
```

The `showframe` package is only used to show the margins of the text block.

[image]

If you also use the `\syllogTA` command, other changes are needed.